# How to do condition statement in LINQ based on code variables?

Tags: c#, linq

I realized that for some odd reason you can't chain the .Where() after the .Select(), so I came up with this.

```
var eventCalendar = db.EventCalendars.Where(q => q.Date == e.Day.Date);

if (!isLogged)
{
    eventCalendar = eventCalendar.Where(q => q.ClientFlag == true);
}
eventCalendar = eventCalendar.Select(q => q.EnvironmentId).Distinct();
```

but now I get and error at the .Select

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<short>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<IT_Portal.EventCalendar>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
```

What am I doing wrong?  To put it simply, I just want to be able to grab Distinct Environment ID from the Calendar Event table so that I can notify users if there is an event occurring that day on a specific environment.  Finally if the user is not logged in, get only Environment Id from events that are marked to be displayed for client (ClientFlag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new variable.

```
var environmentIDs = eventCalendar.Select(q => q.EnvironmentId).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your last line is the problem. You're trying to re-use a local variable that is a different type than you're assigning to it. You just need to change it slightly:

```
var eventCalendarEnvironmentIds = 
    eventCalendar.Select(q => q.EnvironmentId).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

By selecting  Select(q => q.EnvironmentId) you are actually selecting the EnvironmentId and not the eventCalenderObject.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
var eventCalendar = db.EventCalendars.Where(q => q.Date == e.Day.Date);
```

to:

```
 // I specify IQueryable, you can use 'var' - you simply need to change the variable name
IQueryable eventQuery = db.EventCalendars.Where(q => q.Date == e.Day.Date);
```

Then, selecting:

```
var eventCalendar = eventQuery.Select(q => q.EnvironmentId).Distinct();
```

Sometimes, when you continue to use `var`, you may lose sight of the data type. You should use the actual data type as often as you can. Getting caught in the trap of using var is not a good practice, IMO.